# How to convert my text overflow into columns?

Tags: javascript, html, css, multiple-columns, dynamic-columns

I need to force my text overflow into a new column within a set div height.

This is what it is currently doing:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2efoD.png

This is what I need it to do. (this was mocked up in photoshop)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/waRcQ.jpg

Here is the html

```
<div class="data">
<div class="stackleft" id="p1_stack"></div>
<div class="stackright" id="p2_stack"></div>
</div>
```

Here is the JavaScript

```
function drawStack(isFinal){
var stackLength = Oscore[currentPlayer].stack.length;
var temp = "";
var tot = 0;
for(var i=0;i<stackLength;i++){
    var val = Oscore[currentPlayer].stack[i];
    temp += val + "<br>";
    tot += val;
}
//if(!isFinal){
    //temp = '<div class="workingScore">'+scoreTemp+'</div><br>' + temp;
//}
var writeSore = document.form1.game.value - tot;
writeit(writeSore,currentPlayer + "_score");
writeit(temp,currentPlayer + "_stack");
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks in advance.

Comment: bcoz u are putting <br/> with js so it is in next line  try ul and li and make them inline-block it works fine then

Comment: can you show the html browser renders for this snippet

Comment: I am unsure what you are asking, if you are asking for the output from the js then its not outputting anything in the html. Also I tried changing br/ to ul and it moves all the text to new columns every time  it makes a new number.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for either:

1. Multiple column CSS layout - [See supported browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=column)
2. CSS Regions - Currently still a working draft and not widely supported however there's a [polyfill created by Adobe](https://github.com/adobe-webplatform/css-regions-polyfill)

It looks like you're dealing with a smart phone browsers. So support for these features in Safari and Chrome is accepted as long as you don't care for IE